# How to convert a column of type TEXT to VARCHAR?

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to convert a column with data in it as `TEXT` to `VARCHAR(X)` easily? There are no existing records in the column is longer than `X`.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Yes for sure

`ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY column_name VARCHAR(X)`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your super quick answer :)

Comment: Should be using varchar(max) afaik unless maybe X is very small

Answer (score 9):

For MS SQL:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ALTER COLUMN column_name datatype(value)
```

For MySQL

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
MODIFY column_name datatype(value)
```

Comment: Presumably `datatype(value)` is the target type and not the source type?

Answer (score 1):

I used this for mass change of my DB. Execute it, then copy all rows, paste into query field, remove header and run.

Change ENGINE, CHARSET and COLLATION of all tables in DB=itsd:

```
SELECT CONCAT("ALTER TABLE ", TABLE_SCHEMA, '.', TABLE_NAME," ENGINE=INNODB, 
 CHARSET=utf8, COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;") AS ExecuteTheString
 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
 WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA="itsd"
    AND TABLE_TYPE="BASE TABLE";
```

Convert CHARSET and COLLATION of all tables in DB=itsd:

```
SELECT CONCAT("ALTER TABLE ", TABLE_SCHEMA, '.', TABLE_NAME," CONVERT TO 
 CHARACTER SET utf8;") AS ExecuteTheString
 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
 WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA="itsd"
    AND TABLE_TYPE="BASE TABLE";
```

Change all TEXT fields to VARCHAR(255) of all tables in DB=itsd:

```
 SELECT CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ', table_schema, '.', table_name, ' MODIFY COLUMN ', 
 column_name, ' VARCHAR(255);')
 FROM information_schema.columns
 WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'itsd'
    AND DATA_TYPE = 'text' 
    AND TABLE_TYPE="BASE TABLE";
```

Answer (score 0):

For postgres

```
ALTER TABLE "table_name" ALTER COLUMN "column_name" TYPE VARCHAR(x);
```